# Did this couple lose 500 pounds of weight in 2 years?

Tags: nutrition

According to this post on a Facebook page, this couple lost 500 pounds of weight in 2 years. Is it real or just a fake post?

[image]

Comment: It is easy to find newspaper articles and interviews of this couple. Is that sufficient evidence? If not, what would it take to convince you?

Comment: @Oddthinking i just needed references, which i have got now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Their story was told on several news outlets:

- [ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/lifestyle/2013/09/husband-and-wife-lose-over-500-pounds-together/) -- "Husband and Wife Lose Over 500 Pounds Together" (September 17, 2013)
- [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/09/16/i-lost-weight-justin-lauren-shelton_n_3719785.html) -- "I Lost Weight: Justin And Lauren Shelton Lost More Than 500 Pounds Together" (September 16, 2013)
- [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2423614/Husband-wife-reveal-unbelievable-transformation-losing-combined-524-POUNDS-19-months.html) -- "Husband and wife reveal their unbelievable transformation after losing a combined 524 POUNDS in 19 months" (September 17, 2013)
- [Today (NBC News)](http://www.today.com/video/today/53023582#53023582) -- "Husband, wife lose more than 500 pounds" (September 16, 2013)

Maybe that's sufficient evidence: the standard for this site requires that the evidence referenced in an answer must be better than the evidence presented/questions in the OP; I hope that national news stories (in this answer) are better, more fact-checked, than an unknown Facebook page (in the OP).